# Update from CentOS 7.5.1804 to 7.6 running into package conflict errors

Tags: centos7

I have a Centos VM running Gnome that I regularly run yum update on to keep it current with the latest updates.  Today I ran

```
sudo yum update -y
```

as I typically do and it failed with multiple package conflicts.  If tried a few  alternatives (I didn't do the --skip-broken as suggested for fear that it might break the machine).

Any ideas on how to get around this would be greatly welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a further update to the latest contents of the CentOS repos has resolved my problem.  The update completed without error and the system is running CentOS 7.6.1810